# JComponent for images with no zoom for HiDPI

Tags: java, image, swing, hidpi

I'd like to have a component that shows an image in Java without zooming on HiDPI screens.

The obvious candidate is to use a JLabel. I've succesfully done it by overwriting the `AffineTransform` in `paintComponent` but it remains the problem that the label preferred size is incorrect on HiDPI.

The following example seems to work even when I move the window from HiDPI (4K scaled 1.75) to FullHD (scale 1.0) except for the size of the component on HiDPI which is larger than the image displayed.

How can I achieve to have the preferred size of a component not to be zoomed on a HiDPI screen?

```
public class UnscaledImage extends JPanel {

    private AffineTransform noChangeTransform = new AffineTransform();
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private JLabel colorLabel = new JLabel("Color");
    private BufferedImage image;
    private double scale = 1.0;

    public UnscaledImage() {
        initUI();
        packAndShow("Unscaled Image");
    }

    public void initUI() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        ImageIcon imageIcon = (ImageIcon) UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");
        image = new BufferedImage(imageIcon.getIconWidth(), imageIcon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(imageIcon.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();
        imageLabel = new JLabel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                AffineTransform oldTransform = g2d.getTransform();
                scale = oldTransform.getScaleX();
                Dimension labelPrefSize = imageLabel.getPreferredSize();
                if (scale != 1.0 && labelPrefSize.width == image.getWidth()) {
                    imageLabel.setSize(new Dimension((int) (labelPrefSize.width / scale), (int) (labelPrefSize.height / scale)));
                    SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(imageLabel).pack();
                }
                g2d.setTransform(noChangeTransform);
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g2d.setTransform(oldTransform);
            }
        };
        imageLabel.setIcon(imageIcon);
        imageLabel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
                int mouseX = (int) (me.getX() * scale);
                int mouseY = (int) (me.getY() * scale);
                if (mouseX < image.getWidth() && mouseY < image.getHeight()) {
                    int color = image.getRGB(mouseX, mouseY);
                    colorLabel.setBackground(new Color(color));
                }
            }
        });
        colorLabel.setOpaque(true);
        colorLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(colorLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void packAndShow(String title) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public final static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new UnscaledImage());
    }
}
```